# convert number to words ,in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I need to write numbers like:
1>yek

123>yeksad o bist o se

1,123>yek hezar o yeksad o bist o se

3,002,001>se milion o do hezar o yek ...

I,m beginner in objective c :)

**I write it in c but I want to convert it ,into obj_c! How can i do that?**

somthing like:

```
const char  *yekan[10]={"","yek","do","se","chahar","panj","shesh","haft","hasht","noh"};
char ary[9]={'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};

// get a number from user & converting it to string

// user number: 123 > the number in ary:000 000 123) 

// '3' => 3

m=(int) ary[8]; 
m=m-'0'; 

if (j==3)   { printf(" %s ",yekan[m]);} // yekan[3] = se 

output: se
```

thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

NSNumberFormatter class has built-in functionality for conversion numbers to words:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
[formatter setLocale:...]; // Set locale if you want to use something other then the current one
NSString* numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 100]];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :), but how can i set locale to persian env...?

Comment: Wo0oW i can set persianlocal :) 

NSLocale *persianLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];

thanks again:*

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of @Vladimir answer (Just in case)

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .SpellOutStyle
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
let string = formatter.stringFromNumber(55015515)
```