# Objective-C loop needed

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I need some help on automating this with a loop (as I have 500+ buttons). The code is bellow. Thank you.

```
MyButton *button1 = [[MyButton alloc] init];

button1.name = @"One";
button1.controller = self;
button1.image = [NSImage imageNamed:button1.name];

_buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayController addObject:button1];

MyButton *button2 = [[MyButton alloc] init];

button2.name = @"Two";
button2.controller = self;
button2.image = [NSImage imageNamed:button2.name];

_buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayController addObject:button2];
```

Comment: ugh what's purpose of `_buttonArray`?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen to put the object in the array

Comment: Isn't the same as `arrayController`?

Comment: And are you sure that you have 500 images for all 500 buttons?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I guess it is. Basically i have an array controller in my xib file and I am trying to store these objects in that Array Controller. I don't know another way to do it... And this works, but I have a lot of these buttons and I would like to automate this, so that I would have to change button number every time..

Comment: Do you mean to store your buttons in _buttonArray? Why do you keep recreating it?

Comment: Create a method to create a button given a name. Then call that method from a for loop. The hard part if the button names, what are you going to can button 125, "OneTwentyFive"? Better to name them "Button125", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Better to name the buttons with a pattern like: "Button125", etc.

Example code, not tested:

```
for (int i=1; i<= 500; i++) {
    [MyClass createButtonNumber:i]; // Where MyClass is the class name this code is in.
}

+ (MyButton *)createButtonNumber:(int)number {
    MyButton *button = [MyButton new];
    button.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%03i", number];
    button.controller = self;
    button.image = [NSImage imageNamed: button.name];
    [arrayController addObject:button];

    return button; // Just incase it is needed.
}
```

Note: The following code repeated for each button makes no sense and has been left out of the example code.

```
_buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Just a thought, I think it might be useful to give each button a tag corresponding with the number of the button. It would make for cleaner/easier referencing later on, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 500; ++i) {
    MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc] init];

    button.name = ...; // Needs a method to convert from i to corresponding English words
    button.controller = self;
    button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:button.name];

    [arrayController addObject:button];
}
```

You need an algorithm to convert from `i` to English words (e.g `1` to `"One"`, `2` to `"Two"` etc). This can be done with an `NSNumberFormatter` with `numberStyle` set to `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377510/convert-number-to-words-in-objective-c) for more info.

You still needs 500+ images named according to the buttons' names.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a guess, but `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` might be what you need. I can think of no sane reason to use 500 `UIButtons`.

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question. This should be a comment at best.